# Database won't update a table using OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, oledb

[image]

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM EMP", "Provider = OraOLEDB.Oracle;Driver=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=192.168.1.25/ORA8I;User id=INTERNSHIP;Password=123");
        cmd = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

        adapter.Update(ds, "EMP");
        MessageBox.Show("information updated", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
   }
   catch
   {
        MessageBox.Show("There is nothing to update");
   }
}
```

Note: using oracle 11g databse. `Dataset` ds is set during form loading as `Dataset ds = new Dataset();`

> Error: Dynamic sql generation against select command.

But i have set **phno as my primary key**.

Comment: Could you please provide more information. What is the exception? How do you fill the dataset in?

Comment: filled it during initialization. adapter.fill(ds,"emp"). that doesn't seem to be the problem though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to initialize a dataset from the database you should use the [`Fill`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the `OleDbDataAdapter` class instead of the `Update` method

```
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

The error tells that there is a need to specify the fields of the table you want to update. The easiest way is to generate the update statement using the `OleDbCommandBuilder` class.

```
 adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM EMP", "...");
 cmd = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
 adapter.UpdateCommand = cmd.GetUpdateCommand();
 adapter.Update(ds, "EMP");
```

The builder will generate the update statement and specify all fields.

Don't forget to dispose the resources you use (connection, adapter, command, etc.). Just call the `Dispose` method in the end:

```
adapter.Dispose();
```

or use the `using` keyword

```
using (adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("...", "..."))
{
}
```

Comment: i think you could help now. provided more details to the error